# Update oracle using dataset in .NET 1.1

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I have done a code where I update the given dataset into oracle database using the adapter.Update method in .NET 2.0
However the same piece of code gives exception
"Update requires a valid InsertCommand when passed DataRow collection with new rows"

In case I traverse the dataset and insert each row , it takes a lot of time(over 5000 records).

Please suggest a way to update whole dataset into database at a time.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is one row at a time

```
conn=objDbClass.open_connection();
string cmdStr = "select COL1, COL2   from MY_TABLE";
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdStr, conn);
OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
DataSet dataset1 = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(dataset1,"Table1");
string err_txt="";
int err_cnt=0;
int call_no=Find_CallNo();
for (int arcnt=0;arcnt
DataRow dr1=dataset1.Tables[0].NewRow();
dr1["COL1"]=drxl["COL1"].ToString();
dr1["COL2"]=drxl["COL2"].ToString();
dataset1.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr1);
int no_updated_rows = adapter.Update(dataset1,"Table1");
int len = xlds.Tables[0].Columns.Count;
}
}
}
```

Here for each row is read from the excel and placed in the dataset's data table. Then the update function of the data adapter is called. hence, in case, if the dataset has 40 rows, the update function will be called 40 times.